# Measure top memory consumption (linux program)

Tags: memory, memory-management

How can I measure the top (the maximum) memory usage of some programm?

It do a lot of malloc/free, and run rather fast, so I can't see the max memory in top.

I want smth like `time` utility:

```
$ time ./program
real xx sec
user xx sec
sys  xx sec
```

and

```
$ mem_report ./program
max memory used  xx mb
shared mem       xx mb
```

Comment: I understand you want an existing program, don't you? Cause if it is your program you can handle it in a different way.

Comment: What language? Why not run it from within the/a debugger?

Comment: Yes, it is about measuring a existing executable. It is written in C, but I want to get an utility, easy to use as `time`. Running from debugger does'nt help, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time` call is your shell. If you call `/usr/bin/time`, the program, you will get some knowledge of resident memory usage. Note however that it may not count memory-mapped files, shared memory and other details which you may need.

Comment: It doesn't, only pagefaults are reported, but not memory. `(0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (1major+1822minor)pagefaults 0swaps`

Comment: That is odd. Even a meek `wc` of `/etc/hosts` yields some RSS usage. Perhaps your program exits long before a poll of the stats occurs.

Comment: so `/usr/bin/time` utility uses polling too? runtime is 0.3 sec of user, 3 sec of real.

Comment: $ /usr/bin/time wc /etc/hosts >/dev/null
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+180minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Comment: long running programs too :  $ /usr/bin/time bc>/dev/null
2^3453456
38.48user 0.00system 0:44.83elapsed 85%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+4060minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Comment: I'd be willing to wager it is something in your linux setup which prevents you from getting the data. Your output is different from mine. Basically, `/usr/bin/time` simply uses `wait3(2)` internally, see the man page `time(1)` in the *ACCURACY* section. It takes an interesting `-v` (verbose) parameter as well.

Comment: my time is Gnu time 1.7. Checked its run with `strace -v` - `wait4` syscall returns 0 in `ru_*rss`. My Linux was Gentoo based, kernel was 2.6.28. The same result on ubuntu 8.04. LTS. What is your distro/kernel? Seems to be a kernel config parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux, you can wrap your program in a script that polls:

```
# for your current process
/proc/self/statm

# or a process you know the pid of
/proc/{pid}/statm
```

and writes out the results - you can aggregate them afterwards.